# Using MS Graph to Read Excel Contents Through Sharepoint

Tags: c#, excel, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm attempting to use MS Graph to parse the contents of excel files and sync the data with other business-line applications. The issue I'm running into is actually getting at the data in excel.

I'm using a `ClientCredentialProvider` authenticating to an Azure AD App Registration which has FullControl and Read.All permissions in my tenant to create my `GraphServiceClient`, and can successfully query the Site via ID, and even see the document library I'm trying to access, but the `Items` comes up empty. See below

```
var result = _graphService.Client
                .Sites["my-site-id"] // This works                
                .Drives["site-drive-id"] // This works to find the document library
                //.Lists["list-id-corresponding-to-folder"] // This also works to find that folder
                .Items // ****This is null****
                .Request()
                .GetAsync()
                .Result;
```

I tried using the `Lists` property (as noted above) because as I understand it document libraries in SharePoint are really just lists, but again the `Items` enumeration yields no results.

I can't find documentation on Microsoft's site on this use case, and I notice using the MS Graph Explorer that the returned object doesn't have an "items" field (or many properties in the `Microsoft.Graph.Site` class), but I would think there is *some* way to get this field populated since it's implemented in the `Microsoft.Graph` namespace. Not sure if I'm missing some permissions step or what, but if I can access the site with FullControl I should be able to access all its contents...

I can't use `Client.Me` (personal drive) as a source location because 1) the application doesn't run under my permissions and 2) there is a need to read multiple files; the idea would be just provide the needed site/drive/item ID's and get the documents.

Is there some other way I should be going about this?

Comment: To get the list of files in a document library you need to use `/drives/{drive-id}/root/children`, using items directly will not give you the list of files. After you get the document list, get the id of Excel file from them and use `/drives/{drive-id}/Items/{itemid}`

Comment: This worked, and after using the /sites/{id} to find the drive ID I was able to remove the "sites" part of the path which makes things cleaner and just go straight to drive as you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@broccoli_rob,

MS Graph has not exposed the functionality of enumerating all items in a drive. Instead, you can only [list children](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) or [get item by id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

We suggest you use `/drive/root:/{item-path}` to get items in a folder. And you can vaild the endpoint in Graph explorer:

[image]

BR

Comment: Looks like the source of my confusion was expecting the `/items` endpoint to return a result without providing the id; I needed to enumerate those items in order to find the item id, which the `/children` endpoint enabled me to do to. Unfortunately no `Children` field exists in the Graph SDK so you have to use the explorer to find the item id first.

The second link you posted helped me get to the ID I needed so I'll mark this as the answer.